# DT::dataTableOutput() not working on Shiny Server but works when ran from R Studio

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, rstudio-server

Hello I'm having an issue where the command `DT::dataTableOutput("table")`causes r shiny server to crash and report "ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification." What's odd it the shiny app runs perfectly from my local machine and even run without issue when running it from the R studio sever instance i.e. yourserver:8787. I'm running the sever on an Ubuntu 16.04 VM thats hosted by Linode. Full disclosure this is my first time working in Ubuntu let alone navigating it entirely from terminal. My point is I have not been able to pull up the error logs from the Ubuntu terminal because although I know where they are I don't know what command to use to open them. My question is why does the sever crash when the the app runs from RStudio?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)  
library(readr)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

GData <- structure(list(Model = structure(1:2, .Label = c("G17", "G19"), class = "factor"), 
                          Maker = c("G_Inc", "G_Inc"), Type = c("P","P"), 
                          OLength = c(8.03, 8.03), 
                          Length = c(4.48, 4.48), 
                          Site = c(6.49,6.49), 
                          rad = c(1.26, 1.26), 
                          HOB = c(1.18, 1.18), 
                          Width = c(1.18,1.18),
                          BWidth = c(25.06, 25.06), 
                          Weight = c(32.12, 32.12), 
                          WieghtL = c(5.5,5.5), 
                          TPull_lb = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "Striker", class = "factor"),
                          Te = c(17L, 15L), 
                          C_Standard = c(9, 9), 
                          Cer = structure(c(1L,1L), 
                                          .Label = "Para", class = "factor")), 
                     .Names = c("Model","Maker", "Type", "OLength", "Length", "Site", "rad", "HOB", "Width", 
                                                                                                               "BWidth", "Weight", "WieghtL", "TPull_lb", "Te", "C_Standard", 
                                                                                                               "Cer"), row.names = c("1", "2"), class = "data.frame")

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Resorces",
  tabPanel("Search Tool",
           sidebarPanel(
             sliderInput("OveralLength", "Overal Length",
                         min = 2, max = 16,
                         value = c(5,10),step=0.1,post=" in"),
             sliderInput("integer1", "BLength",
                         min = 1, max = 10,
                         value = c(3,6),step=0.1,post=" in"),
             sliderInput("integer2", "TPull",
                         min = 0, max = 15,value = c(3,8),step=0.1,post=" lbs"),
             sliderInput("C_Standard", "Cap",
                         min = 0, max = 33,
                         value = 10),
             selectInput("man",
                         "Manufacturer:",
                         c("All",
                           unique(as.character(GData$Maker)))),
             useShinyjs(),
             actionButton("SelectCol", "Show Columns"),
             actionButton("SelectColOFF", "Hide Columns"),
             hidden(
               checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Select Columns to Show",
                                  names(GData), selected = names(GData))) 

             ,width=3),
           mainPanel(
             tabsetPanel(id="tabs",
                         tabPanel("Hg", 
                                  # Output: Table summarizing the values entered ----
                                  DT::dataTableOutput("table")),
                         tabPanel("Rif"),
                         tabPanel("Sho"),
                         tabPanel("BP"),
                         tabPanel("Misc")
             )
           )
  ),
  tabPanel("C_Database"),
  tabPanel("W_Center")
)
server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$SelectCol, {
    show("show_vars")
  })
  observeEvent(input$SelectColOFF, {
    hide("show_vars")
  })


  # Create gun table
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(subset(GData[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Look for the error logs by typing `cd /var/log/shiny-server/<your-app>` then `ls -lart` then open the last one with `less <log-filename>`.

Comment: you can also use `vim <log-filename>`

Comment: Thanks guys here is the error from the log file. `Error in loadNamespace(name):there is no package called "crosstalk"
Calls:runApp ... tryCatch -> trCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Excecution halted`. Thanks will try installing that package tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, your problem is discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543844/error-when-launching-shiny-app-in-ec2-instance/47554306#47554306 . Not all packages are available to the shiny user. Try the answer I gave there and see if it works

Comment: @BertilNestorius thanks. It appears the `DT` and `crosstalk` package are in the user library not the system library. Hopefully this change will fix the issue.